# How to set value of an input from Redux store, but then still be able to write in that input and update value?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

My input is also like a searchbox: I want to be able to search for names on the input but then I want to be able to click a name from the dropdown search results and set the input with that value. I then want to be able to search again if I want to change that value.

Tried using DefaultValue and uncontrolled components, but neither worked. Not sure if I used them right though.

```js
class PublishTest extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      showRows: false,
      numberOfRows: ["row"],
      search: "",
      searchResults: [],
      insightListActive: false,
      insightTagsActive: false
    };

    this.hideOrShowRows = this.hideOrShowRows.bind(this);
    this.addNewRow = this.addNewRow.bind(this);
    this.searchAllUsers = this.searchAllUsers.bind(this);
    this.onChangeInsight = this.onChangeInsight.bind(this);
    this.clearInput = this.clearInput.bind(this);
    this.clearInsightList = this.clearInsightList.bind(this);
    this.searchInsightTags = this.searchInsightTags.bind(this);
    this.clearTagList = this.clearTagList.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getLoginCredential();
    this.props.getAllRoles();
  }

  hideOrShowRows() {
    this.setState({
      showRows: !this.state.showRows
    });
  }

  addNewRow() {
    this.setState({
      numberOfRows: [...this.state.numberOfRows, "row"]
    });
  }

  searchAllUsers(e) {
    this.setState({
      search: e.target.value
    });

    const searchOption = this.state.search;

    fetch("http://localhost:3500/soiapi/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        data: [
          {
            name: "searchUser",
            urlparameter: { search: searchOption, appId: "1" },
            parameter: ""
          }
        ]
      })
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          searchResults: data[0]
        });
      });
  }

  onChangeInsight = e => {
    this.props.insightOnChangeValue(e.target.value);
    this.props.searchInsights(e.target.value);

    this.setState({
      insightListActive: true
    });
  };

  clearInput() {
    this.setState({
      search: "",
      searchResults: []
    });
  }

  clearInsightList() {
    this.setState({
      insightListActive: false
    });
  }

  searchInsightTags(e) {
    this.props.getInsightTags(e.target.value);
    this.setState({
      insightTagsActive: true
    });
  }

  clearTagList() {
    this.setState({
      insightTagsActive: false
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { searchResults } = this.state;

    let rows;
    let button;
    let icon;

    if (this.state.showRows) {
      rows = this.state.numberOfRows.map((row, i) => (
        <div>
          <Row index={i} />
        </div>
      ));
      button = (
        <button
          onClick={this.addNewRow}
          className="Button--secondary float-right"
        >
          Add Row
        </button>
      );
      icon = (
        <i aria-hidden="true" className="Icon Icon--minus-small iconFont"></i>
      );
    } else if (!this.state.showRows) {
      icon = (
        <i aria-hidden="true" className="Icon Icon--plus-small iconFont"></i>
      );
    }

    if (this.props.user.userDTO) {
      const { userDTO } = this.props.user;

      const insightSearchResults = this.props.insightReducerValue
        .insightList[0];

      return (
        <div style={{ padding: "5px" }} className="publish-container">
          <h4 className="publish-h4">Publish Insights</h4>
          <h6 className="publish-h6">Insight Details</h6>
          <hr className="line-style" />
          <section id="publish-section-1">
            <div class="Grid">
              <div class="Col Col--3">
                <div class="grid-block">
                  <div className="Form-group publish-insights-input">
                    <label className="Form-label insight-label">
                      Insight Name <span className="asterisk">*</span>:
                    </label>
                    <div id="insight-container">
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Insight Name"
                        onChange={this.onChangeInsight}
                        onFocus={this.clearInsightList}
                        onBlur={this.clearInsightList}
                        className="Form-input"
                        value={this.props.insightReducerValue.insightValue}
                      />
                      {this.state.insightListActive ? (
                        <InsightList insights={insightSearchResults} />
                      ) : null}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="Col Col--3">
                <div class="grid-block">
                  <div class="Form-group publish-insights-input">
                    <label class="Form-label">
                      Insight Source <span className="asterisk">*</span>:
                    </label>
                    <select
                      id="insight-source"
                      role="combobox"
                      class="Form-input"
                    >
                      <option
                        disabled="disabled"
                        selected="selected"
                        aria-disabled="true"
                      >
                        Choose one
                      </option>
                      <option>Tableau</option>
                      <option>Qlik</option>
                      <option>D3JS</option>
                      <option>CXI</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
          <section id="publish-section-2">
            <div class="Grid">
              <div class="Col Col--6">
                <div class="grid-block">
                  <div className="Form-group publish-insights-input">
                    <label class="Form-label">
                      URL <span className="asterisk">*</span>:
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="URL" class="Form-input" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
          <section id="publish-section-3">
            <div class="Grid">
              <div class="Col Col--6">
                <div class="grid-block">
                  <div className="publish-insights-input">
                    <label class="Form-label">
                      Description <span className="asterisk">*</span>:
                    </label>
                    <textarea
                      placeholder="Description"
                      class="Form-input"
                    ></textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>

          <section id="publish-section-4">
            <div class="Grid">
              <div class="Col Col--3">
                <div class="grid-block">
                  <div className="Form-group publish-insights-input">
                    <label className="Form-label third-div-p">
                      POC Name <span className="asterisk">*</span>:
                    </label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="Name"
                      className="Form-input"
                      value={`${userDTO.firstName} ${userDTO.lastName}`}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="Col Col--3">
                <div class="grid-block">
                  <div className="Form-group publish-insights-input">
                    <label className="Form-label third-div-p">
                      Group Distro (E-mail Address)
                      <span className="asterisk">*</span>:
                    </label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="Email"
                      class="Form-input"
                      value={userDTO.emailAddress}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
          <section id="publish-section-5">
            <div class="Grid">
              <div class="Col Col--6">
                <div class="grid-block">
                  <div class="Form-group publish-insights-input">
                    <div class="Form-checkbox is-restricted">
                      <input
                        id="restricted"
                        name="checkboxDefault"
                        type="checkbox"
                      />
                      <label for="restricted">Is Restricted</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
          <section id="publish-section-6">
            <div class="Grid">
              <div class="Col Col--2">
                <div class="grid-block">
                  <div id="tree-section">
                    <label id="category-label" className="Form-label">
                      Category <span className="asterisk">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <div id="tree-container">
                      <PublishInsightsTree />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="Col Col--4">
                <div class="grid-block">
                  <div className="Form-group publish-insights-input">
                    <label className="Form-label third-div-p">
                      Add Insight Tags <span className="asterisk">*</span>:
                    </label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      onChange={e => this.searchInsightTags(e)}
                      onFocus={this.clearTagList}
                      onBlur={this.clearTagList}
                      placeholder="Write some insight tags"
                      className="Form-input"
                    />
                  </div>
                  {
                  this.state.insightTagsActive ? 
                  <div>
                    {
                      this.props.insightTags ?
                      <InsightTags tags={this.props.insightTags[0]} />
                      : null
                    }
                  </div>
                  : null
                }
                </div>
                <div class="grid-block">
                  <div class="Grid">
                    <div class="Col Col--7 img-url-input">
                      <div class="grid-block">
                        <div
                          id="file-div"
                          class="Form-group publish-insights-input"
                        >
                          <label class="Form-label">
                            Image URL <span className="asterisk">*</span>:
                          </label>
                          <input
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Insight Name"
                            class="Form-input"
                          />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Col Col--5">
                      <div class="grid-block">
                        <button class="Button--secondary upload-image-button">
                          Upload Image
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="Col Col--7 url-description">
                      <div class="grid-block">
                        <p>
                          Please copy paste the generated URL after uploading
                          image file.
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
          <section id="publish-section-7">
            <h6 className="publish-h6">Role Details</h6>
            <hr className="line-style" />
          </section>
          <section id="publish-section-8">
            <div class="Grid">
              <div class="Col Col--2">
                <div class="grid-block">
                  <label id="roles-label" className="Form-label">
                    Assign to Role <span className="asterisk">*</span>
                  </label>
                  <div id="all-roles">
                    {this.props.listOfRoles ? (
                      <ListOfRoles roles={this.props.listOfRoles} />
                    ) : null}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="Col Col--4">
                <div class="grid-block assign-user-div">
                  <label className="Form-label label-spacing">
                    Assign to Individual User:
                  </label>
                  <div className="Form-group">
                    <textarea
                      onChange={this.searchAllUsers}
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="Look up by EID/Name"
                      onFocus={this.clearInput}
                      onBlur={this.clearInput}
                      className="Form-input assign-user-textarea"
                      value={this.state.search}
                    ></textarea>
                    {searchResults.length > 0 ? (
                      <div id="user-list">
                        {searchResults ? (
                          <UserList searchResults={this.state.searchResults} />
                        ) : null}
                      </div>
                    ) : null}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
          <section id="publish-section-9">
            <h6 className="publish-h6 metadata-heading" onClick={this.hideOrShowRows}>
              <span id="metadata-icon">{icon}</span>
              Metadata Info
            </h6>
            <hr className="line-style color" />
          </section>
          <section id="publish-section-10">
            <div class="Grid">
              <div class="Col Col--12 add-row-col">
                <div class="grid-block">{button}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            {rows}
          </section>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  user: state.LoginReducer.loginInfo,
  searchUser: state.LoginReducer.searchUser,
  insightReducerValue: state.SideDrawerReducer,
  listOfRoles: state.LoginReducer.listOfRoles,
  insightTags: state.SideDrawerReducer.insightTags
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {
    getLoginCredential,
    searchUser,
    insightOnChangeValue,
    searchInsights,
    getAllRoles,
    getInsightTags
  }
)(PublishTest);
```

This is the part of the code I need help with:

```js
 <input
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Insight Name"
                        onChange={this.onChangeInsight}
                        onFocus={this.clearInsightList}
                        onBlur={this.clearInsightList}
                        className="Form-input"
                        value={this.props.insightReducerValue.insightValue}
                      />
                      {this.state.insightListActive ? (
                        <InsightList insights={insightSearchResults} />
                      ) : null}
```

Comment: Why not set a state with the `insightValue` as what you get from the props. Then you can edit it directly in state. instead of having to set it straight on your props from redux?

Comment: @Claeusdev - how can I do that exactly?

Comment: @AnnahI, Since your code was a little hard to go through, I created a sample app for you to check out, might give you a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Since your code is a little messy, I made a sandbox that fetches some data from a dummy API, stores that data to our local component state. We have a text field where we can type in usernames and a list of matching usernames will appear as a dummy drop, clicking any one of those usernames will set the value in the text field. It's pretty straight forward will give you an idea on how to get started.

**EDIT:**
**Sandbox Link:** https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-pascal-pf3hd?fontsize=14

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    input: "",
    users: [],
    dropdown: []
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    let users = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
    users = await users.json();
    this.setState({ users });
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ input: e.target.value }, () => {
      let results = this.state.users.filter(user => {
        return user.username.indexOf(this.state.input) > -1;
      });
      this.setState({ dropdown: results });
    });
  };

  handleSelect = username => e => {
    this.setState({ input: username }, () => this.setState({ dropdown: [] }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Search</h1>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="input"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={this.state.input}
        />

        {this.state.dropdown.map(d => (
          <h3 onClick={this.handleSelect(d.username)} key={d.id}>
            {d.username}
          </h3>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you start off by loading all possible search results into state or props (e.g. under `this.props.searchResults`)? Then you could try using the [datalist](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp) tag. Not quite sure if this was what you were going for, but it looked like something like that could work for you.

```
<input type="text"
       defaultValue={this.props.insightReducerValue.insightValue}
       list="inputOptions"
       onChange={(e) => console.log("Current input field value: ", e.target.value)} />

<datalist id="inputOptions">
    {this.props.searchResults.map((item, key) =>
        <option key={key} value={item} />
    )}
</datalist>
```

P.S. Check the supported browsers list under the [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp).

Comment: I am just not sure if this would work though because I don't want to have a defaultValue. I only want the value to be change to `this.props.insightReducerValue.insightValue` if that item is clicked in the datalist. So I am just not sure how to do that....